Origin type array not working in nextjs-cors
In the official CORS package of nextjs-cors documentation, I see that an array of domains can be passed as origin value: https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuration-options
here is a code snippet
import type { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import NextCors from 'nextjs-cors';
import redisService from '../../../utils/services/redis-service';

type ResponseData = {
  message: string;
};

export default async function handler(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse<ResponseData>) {
  try {
    await NextCors(req, res, {
      // Options
      methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
      origin: [
        'https://sample1.com',
        'https://sample2.com',
        'http://sample3.com',
      ],
      optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
    });
    const result = await redisService(req?.query?.redisKey);
    if (result) {
      res.status(200).json(result);
    } else {
      res.status(400).json({
        message: 'Error occured',
      });
    }
  } catch (err: any) {
    res.status(400).json({
      message: err?.message,
    });
  }
}

export async function getRedisData(redisKey: string) {
  const result = await redisService(redisKey);
  return result;
}

I am using the 2.1.2 version of nextjs-cors. and 13.1.1 version of nextjs. if I give a string instead of an array of strings it's working.

Define "working" and "not working". Are you getting a CORS error in one case and not the other? If so, what does the error message say?

@jub0bs i am not getting any error. the issue is when i give origin as a array i am not able to  see Access-Control-Allow-Origin in the response header on network tab of  browser. but if i give  origin as '*' then in response header i am able to see Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *. so my issue is i am not albe to see Access-Control-Allow-Origin when i give origin as a array of strings

The absence of an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in the response would trigger a CORS error in your browser's Console tab. It likely indicates that you're not listing the required origin(s) correctly in the origin array.

@jub0bs i am giving it coreclty.  when I give one as an string its working  and showing  in the network tab. but only when I give array of strings its not showing in network tab

Unless you can post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, I'm inclined to close this as "Not reproducible".
